# How to blocking read a queue in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm new to js and async programming and I'm trying to pass the keyboard event to a running wasm instance.

I'm using [wasm-clang](https://github.com/binji/wasm-clang) to build and run simple c programs in browser, but it's [in-memory file system](https://github.com/binji/llvm-project/blob/master/binji/memfs.c) don't support reading from stdin, as described in [this issue](https://github.com/binji/wasm-clang/issues/5). I'm trying to write a patch of the [memfs.c](https://github.com/binji/llvm-project/blob/master/binji/memfs.c), by importing a JavaScript function and call it when reading from stdin.

In short, how to make a message queue which can blocking read, and export the read function to WebAssembly?

Comment: No, `await` is only valid inside `async` functions. Besides that, what "message queue" are you talking about? It is hard to give proper advice based on the code given.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the specifics of your message queue but:

You cannot use await unless you are within an async function, and async/await are based around promises so you need to think more about how they work, than as await being a 'block here' keyword

assuming someQueue.pop() returns a promise (async) rather than a synchronous value:

promises:

```
someQueue.pop()
    .then(val => {
         doSomething(val)
    })
    .catch(err => handleErr(err))
```

await/async:

```
async function read() {
     let val = await someQueue.pop()
     doSomething(val)
}
```

either way, you must put the 'doSomething' logic inside the promise or async function because javascript cannot pause execution to wait for asynchronous logic to complete

I suggest learning to use promises, then how that relates to async/await. It's a little confusing at first but really easy to understand and use once it clicks

Comment: But can promises act as a blocking function in WebAssembly?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by 'in' wsm. assuming its an exported function, it's pretty much like a normal js function

Comment: I mean the "importObject" of wasm, which can be called by a wasm function.

Comment: honestly - I think we're going to need more info on exactly what you want to achieve in order to give helpful advice. Probably best to edit your question with this and preferably some code